Filetype issue in nvim-autoclose settings
I am using Neovim v.0.10.1 and the autoclose plugin. I have disabled autoclose for the symbol ' on .txt and .tex files, since I mostly write prose in these documents and I don't want to autoclose my apostrophes.
The line in my config that does this is:
["'"] = { close = true, pair = "''", disabled_filetypes = { "tex", "txt" } }

However, this does not behave as expected in various filestypes.
When that line is not in my config, I get the default autoclose behavior: pressing ' once gives this (cursor represented by pipe):
'|'

and pressing ' again closes the quote:
''|

However, if the above line is in my config, pressing ' once gives
'|'

and pressing it again gives
''|''

If I continue to press ', I just keep embedding my cursor deeper in single quotes. This behavior occurs in many filetypes, such as .py, .json, .cpp, and perhaps most surprisingly of all, .tex. But it does not occur in .txt files—that is, it behaves correctly in .txt files.
Here is an init.lua file to reproduce the issue (consisting mostly of the required setup for lazy.nvim plugin manager and the nvim-autoclose plugin):
local opt = vim.opt

-- tabs and indents
opt.tabstop = 2 -- tab width (spaces)
opt.shiftwidth = 2 -- indent width (spaces)
opt.expandtab = false -- turn tabs into spaces
opt.autoindent = true -- copy indent from current line when starting a new one
opt.smartindent = true



-- setting up Lazy.nvim

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
    vim.fn.system({
        "git",
        "clone",
        "--filter=blob:none",
        "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
        "--branch=stable",
        lazypath,

    })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup({

    "m4xshen/autoclose.nvim",
    event = { "InsertEnter" },
    config = function()
        local autoclose = require("autoclose")
        autoclose.setup({
            keys = {
                -- disables autoclose for `'` for .tex and .txt files
                ["'"] = { close = true, pair = "''", disabled_filetypes = { "tex", "txt" } },
            },
        })
    end,
},
{
    checker = {
        enabled = true,
        notify = false,
    },
    change_detection = {
        notify = false,
    },
})


Welcome to [vi.se]! You might be missing escape = true in your definition, looking at the README the default for single quote is ["'"] = { escape = true, close = true, pair = "''" }, also for TeX files it's possible that they have a filetype of latex instead, you can inspect that with :set ft? when you have the file open to check if it will match what you have in your disable statement. Let me know if this helps, I can post an answer if this indeed fixes your issue.

Thank you! It looks like setting escape = true solved it! I checked the filetype using :set ft? and it returns tex (which is what I had gathered from other places too) so I think that is the correct filetype to use.

At least for the difference in behavior you're seeing when pressing '' twice, you should also include escape = true in your configuration override for single quotes:
["'"] = { escape = true, close = true, pair = "''", disabled_filetypes = { "tex", "txt" } }

If you look at the default config in autoclose README you'll see that for single quote it is:
      ["'"] = { escape = true, close = true, pair = "''" },

So it looks like you were missing the escape = true part in yours.
For the disabled file types, you can try to diagnose that by looking at what file type Neovim detects for specific files where your setup does not work as expected, which you can do using the :set ft? command.
For example, for a text file with extension .txt, Neovim detects it as file type "text"
:set ft?
text

So you should probably use "text" instead of "txt" in your setup.
